# Can we give importance to a person's contributions to one field and ignore those to another?

Tags: rambam, science, commentaries

If an individual, such as a sage or commentator, does or supports something that's completely inaccurate in one field of study of which he claims to have knowledge, does it make sense to give much importance to his contributions to other fields?

For example, רמב"ם has offered commentary and Halachic codes, which we seem to hold in rather high regard, but also seems to adamantly refuse the primitive forms of theories which we now know with near-certainty to be accurate, such as atomism.

If someone is not only incorrect in one claim, but adamantly refuses it, as though he has understanding of the field, in which he apparently does not, how can we treat his contributions to other fields as valid?
In other words, if someone claimed more understanding than he really possessed, and made false claims within one field, do we have any legitimate reason to say he didn't do the same in other fields? This is not necessarily a question about Maimonides, nor am I trying to suggest that he or anyone else is wrong, I just wonder why we regard them as "right" or "qualified" to offer what they do.

Comment: In all likelihood had you lived in any time but the present you would have mocked atomism and embraced the Aristotelian view of the world and your question would be 'how can we trust ploni almoni's chidush in the gemara if he believes the nonsense called atomism?'.

Comment: Jews often focus on Moshe's role as the lawgiver and the midwife of the Jewish people, but seem to downplay the fact that Moshe was a pretty good murderer too.

Comment: If our view of such theories for physical reality have changed, and what was once considered is valid is now considered valid, and vice versa, who's to say the same is not true of religious and philosophical claims?

Comment: So I have to make the question more fact-based wording, so how about this: How can we know that a commentator, Rambam for example, has the authority to say what he does, especially when making very incorrect claims on other issues?

Comment: I suspect you have in mind a certain living rosh hayeshivah who is brilliant with Jewish knowledge but whose opinion on medical topics run counter to 99.9% of medical scholars.  Interestin as that may be, you're sill looking for opinions.

Comment: @YaakovSchectman Don't know if you're still around but if you are, consider this. There is a great, great body of holy classical Jewish literature discussing the nature of rabbinical statements about science and medicine, and how one should look at them. The Rambam even writes that to take certain midrash literally is to mock Chazal. On one foot I am trying to say that Judaism answers your question in a sophisticated way. Secondly, [...]

Comment: @YaakovSchectman Although this question was closed as being primarily opinion-based and probably for other reasons (not about Judaism?), it was in fact answered almost to the letter by the Lubavitcher Rebbe in a certain sicha. He says basically that you would always pick a dentist, even a mediocre one, to fix your teeth, even if an extremely brilliant and world-renowned mathematician were in the same building. Similarly you should go to scholars in the orthodox tradition--even mediocre ones--before you listen to what any secular wizard has to say about Torah.

Comment: I don't understand the basis for the question. I don't know very much about quantum mechanics. Does that mean that when I say the first word in the Torah is בראשית it should be regarded as false? Chazal discuss locusts being spontaneously generated. Since we know that's false, should we throw out the entire Gemara? To use your own example, should we decide the Rambam was an idiot and not listen to anything he says? People can be right about one thing and wrong about another. (Those examples were not to equate myself with such Gedolim, btw.)

Answer (score 6):

If a five-time [Oscar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_Awards) winner makes stupid comments about current political events he knows nothing about, does that mean we shouldn't trust his advice about acting? Of course we should: his acting has been tried and found true. Similarly (though *l'havdil*), any authority the Jewish community as a whole has examined over the years and accepted is a "winner".

Comment: I guess an important part of my question was: how do we know a given commentator, such as the Rambam, is "successful" in his more affiliated-with field? If this is decided by it still being studied nearly a millenium later, as your answer seems to suggest, then this is actually very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for a great answer....this also applies to "Why do we have multiple sites in the Stack Exchange network?" :-P